# Post method in Angular returns 400 Status Code

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am student developer in Angular platform. I have a my own api. And I have post method like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task < ActionResult < User >> LoginUser([FromBody] User _user) {
    var joinedUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.loginName == _user.loginName && u.password == _user.password);

    if (joinedUser == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(joinedUser.userId);
    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new {
        id = _user.userId
    }, user);

}
```

And also I have an angular service to login. When I fill form data, _user is full every time. I mean I am taking value of form correctly. When I send user with service to API, I facing an error like this:

> POST https://localhost:44365/api/User/login 400

this is my Angular service method:

```js
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'bearer example',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
    }),
    withCredentials: false
};


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

private apiUrl = "https://localhost:44365/api/User/login"

LoginUser(_user: User): Observable < User > {
    return this.http.post < User > (this.apiUrl, _user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

this is my cors part:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddDbContext<TwitterAPIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            //app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
            app.Use(async (ctx, next) => {
                await next();
                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
                {
                    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                }
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

What is wrong ? Could you help me at this issue ?

Comment: We don't have enough info here. One thing it might be cors. Can you please supply the code where you allow access with CORS. Another issue might be that the objects dont match. Can you validate that the user object in the client side matches the object on the server side? I also recommend using something like postman, just to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I added cors and Postman works and send data  with 'https://localhost:44365/api/User/login' using  'Content-Type application/problem+json; charset=utf-8' header parameter.

Comment: 400 is possible that your posted data does not bind to the api parameter successfully,Could you show the model of `User` in both angular and web api?Besides, do not use `AllowAnyOrigin()` and `AllowCredentials()` together,use `WithOrigins()` instead

Comment: Also,could you show the exactly error message from F12 network response?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is your .NET method signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> LoginUser([FromBody]User _user)
```

The parameter `User` cannot be used here and shouldn't be as you're not passing any parameters. The `HttpHeaders` don't act as parameters.

What you need is the `[Authorize]` attribute on your method (or controller class) which will validate the bearer token for you, and return a 401 if the bearer token is not valid. You don't need to manually check to see if the credentials are correct.

I'd recommend you following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1) guide from Microsoft in order to get token validation working properly in your .NET project.

Hope this helps!